# Delay after typing shift-o to insert a new line between brackets

Tags: insert-mode, normal-mode

I don't know why it is happening.

Suppose I've got a code like this (let x be our cursor):

```
int main() {x
```

and then

```
int main() {
}x
```

Now I would like to enter the normal mode and type <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd> to insert a new line above `}`.

However this is what happens:

```
int main() {
}Ox
```

and after a while it changes to

```
int main() {
    x
}
```

Here is a video where I was able to reproduce this:

[[image: Video thumbnail]

**Vim hangs for a second when typing shift-o after inserting curly brackets** on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vz170eR6aT0)

---

*Side note: could you please suggest me better tagging for this question? I've got no idea how to tag it.*

Comment: Does the following change anything?: `:set timeout timeoutlen=3000 ttimeoutlen=100`. If so this question might be related: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3261/speed-bump-on-esco-insert-to-normal-to-insert-new-line-above-cursor It's also a setting which is suggested in `:help ttimeoutlen`.